# Horizontal scrollview snapping react native

Tags: ios, react-native, horizontalscrollview, react-native-scrollview

Hi I am trying to achieve `scrollview` snap to center 
like below `gif` link

[Check This Gif](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/79f6b2c710949911f76630d9c1c42a349c7d20c4/687474703a2f2f692e696d6775722e636f6d2f364931437648452e676966)

But unable to do so. Following is my react native code to achieve this.

or is there any method to scroll to  particular index of scrollview elements like android ?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

```
<ScrollView
  style={[styles.imgContainer,{backgroundColor:colorBg,paddingLeft:20}]}
  automaticallyAdjustInsets={false}
  horizontal={true}
  pagingEnabled={true}
  scrollEnabled={true}
  decelerationRate={0}
  snapToAlignment='center'
  snapToInterval={DEVICE_WIDTH-100}
  scrollEventThrottle={16}
  onScroll={(event) => {
    var contentOffsetX=event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x;
    var contentOffsetY=event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y;

    var  cellWidth = (DEVICE_WIDTH-100).toFixed(2);
    var cellHeight=(DEVICE_HEIGHT-200).toFixed(2);

    var  cellIndex = Math.floor(contentOffsetX/ cellWidth);

    // Round to the next cell if the scrolling will stop over halfway to the next cell.
    if ((contentOffsetX- (Math.floor(contentOffsetX / cellWidth) * cellWidth)) > cellWidth) {
      cellIndex++;
    }

    // Adjust stopping point to exact beginning of cell.
    contentOffsetX = cellIndex * cellWidth;
    contentOffsetY= cellIndex * cellHeight;

    event.nativeEvent.contentOffsetX=contentOffsetX;
    event.nativeEvent.contentOffsetY=contentOffsetY;

    // this.setState({contentOffsetX:contentOffsetX,contentOffsetY:contentOffsetY});
    console.log('cellIndex:'+cellIndex);

    console.log("contentOffsetX:"+contentOffsetX);
      // contentOffset={{x:this.state.contentOffsetX,y:0}}
  }}
>
  {rows}

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You don't need other libraries you can do that with ScrollView. All you need is to add the following props in your  component.

```
    horizontal= {true}
    decelerationRate={0}
    snapToInterval={200} //your element width
    snapToAlignment={"center"}
```

Check this snack for more details on how to implement it
https://snack.expo.io/H1CnjIeDb

Comment: Works with `ListView` too which is more performant, because it has all of `ScrollView`'s props.

Comment: what would be the interval if I have a header of X units and margin of Y units as well.

Comment: interval only cares about width, you can get the device width using the Dimension library `const { width } = Dimensions.get('window');` And then just apply all dimensions including margins and what not to the snapToInterval like so `snapToInterval={width - 60}`

Check the expo above for more details

Comment: @William I thought FlatList was generally preferred over ListView?

Comment: @AlxVallejo Yeah good spot, I meant FlatList, always get the damn things confused.

Comment: The accepted answer is still the best solution so far.

Answer (score 14):

Use the `pagingEnabled` property in `ScrollView`.

```
const screenHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;

class Screen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView pagingEnabled>
        <Page1 style={{height: screenHeight}} />
        <Page2 style={{height: screenHeight}} />
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: best and simplest solution today for horizontal!

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to use snapToInterval because of the misalignment for long lists you can use snapToOffsets which is more precise.

for example:

```
const { width } = Dimensions.get('window');
this.IMAGE_WIDTH = width * (1 / 2.5)
this.image_margin = 5
this.nishhar = width - ((this.IMAGE_WIDTH + this.image_margin) * 2 + this.image_margin * 2)

dataNum = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

return (<FlatList
            data={dataNum}
            renderItem={item => {
                return (
                    <View style={{
                        backgroundColor: item.index % 2 == 0 ? 'red' : 'blue',
                        width: this.IMAGE_WIDTH,
                        height: this.IMAGE_WIDTH,
                        marginLeft: this.image_margin,
                        marginRight: this.image_margin,
                    }}>
                    </View>)
            }}
            keyExtractor={this.keyGenerator}
            horizontal={true}
            snapToAlignment={"start"}
            snapToOffsets={[...Array(dataNum.length)].map((x, i) => (i * (this.IMAGE_WIDTH + 2 * this.image_margin) - (this.nishhar * 0.5)))}
            decelerationRate={"fast"}
            pagingEnabled
        />)
```

or you can also checkout this example:
https://snack.expo.io/SyWXFqDAB

Answer (score 3):

Try using the `snapToOffsets` prop. This requires a simple addition and multiplication though.

To create a snapping effect showing 2 elements, and 10pts from left and right elements that are out of bound;

```
// import useWindowDimensions from 'react-native'
const { width: windowWidth } = useWindowDimensions();

// the width of a card in ScrollView
// 20 is so out of bound cards on left & right can have 10pts visible;
const cardWidth = (windowWidth / 2) - 20;

// gap between each cards;
const gap = 16;

const halfGap = gap / 2;

const cardContent = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

// THIS IS THE FUN PART
const snapOffsets = cardContent
      .map((_, index) => {            
        return (cardWidth * index) + (halfGap * index)
      })

// add left and right margin to <Card/> for gap effect,
// as well as width using cardWidth above 
// conditional left margin to first card, and right margin to last card

return (
   <ScrollView
     horizontal={true}
     snapToOffsets={snapOffsets}
   >
     { 
       cardContent.map((item, index, arr) => {
         return (
           <Card 
             key={index} 
             title={item} 
             style={{
               width: cardWidth,
               marginLeft: index == 0 ? gap : 0,
               marginRight: index == arr.length - 1 ? gap : halfGap
             }}
           />
         )
       })
     }
   </ScrollView>
)
```

That's it. You can refactor for vertical mode.

> *For a better edge to edge effect, make sure that ancestor containers don't have padding*

Answer (score 1):

There are several options. Here are two that I've tried and work fine. I prefer the second one because as its doc says "like ListView, this can render hundreds of pages without performance issue".

1. [react-native-page-swiper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-page-swiper)
2. [react-native-viewpager](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-viewpager)

Answer (score 0):

I had problem with FlatList's `snapToInterval` logic on iOS (on horizontal list it didn't always snapped correctly to `start`) - I fixed that with increasing values of below properties (I had single item slider)

```
maxToRenderPerBatch={6}
initialNumToRender={6}
windowSize={6}
```