# How to call horizontal scrollview that switches from one element to the other when scrolling horizontally

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

Anybody knows how to call the behaviour of a horizontal scrollview that switches from one element to the other when horizontally scrolling? (Like some components of the airbnb mobile app) I'm looking to achieve that with react native flatlists.

Comment: Ok so I found the answer in this thread: [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39849648/horizontal-scrollview-snapping-react-native)